# Ocultar teclado com Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, teclado, edittext

Estou fazendo uma aplicação mobile que tem telas em *fragment* com Drawer, e nelas tem `EditText`, mas estou com um problema que ao clicar no `EditText` e depois clicar fora, ou clicar no menu o teclado não some, e atrapalha a visualizar tanto o resto do formulário como o menu Drawer.

E se eu voltar pra Home onde não tem `EditText` ele continua na tela o teclado. Como fazer pra fechar?

Comment: Tive esse problema também, utilizei esta [dica][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Tente criar um listener para ser executado quando o focus do `editText` for removido. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textbox);
EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textbox2);
EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textbox3);

OnFocusChangeListener ofcListener = new MyFocusChangeListener();
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(ofcListener);
editText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(ofcListener);
editText3.setOnFocusChangeListener(ofcListener);
private class MyFocusChangeListener implements OnFocusChangeListener {

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus){

        if(!v.hasFocus) {

            InputMethodManager imm =  (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

        }
    }
}
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412943/hide-soft-keyboard-on-losing-focus

Comment: Acontece que tenho mais de um EditText, então não to conseguindo acertar como ficaria.

Comment: Fiz umas alterações para várias Views, no caso vc seta o listener para todos os seus EditText, no exemplo setei para 3, mas você pode fazer isso dinamicamente caso vc tenha um número X de views.

Answer (score 0):

No onCreateView coloca o código a seguir para esconder o teclado.

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Ou seja:

```
    @Override
     public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
                        final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
          {

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mensal, container,false);     

//esconder teclado
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

                    return view;
          }
```